# How to intall ubuntu and remove windows on lenovo G500s

Tags: 12.04, 13.10

How to install ubuntu on lenovo G500s laptop with windows 8 OS.I want to completely remove windows 8  and install ubuntu.Please tell me how to install.Please tell me complete steps

Answer (score 0):

1. set your BIOS to boot from the CD drive.
2. "boot cd" ( Ultimate Boot CD ), ( hiren's bootcd ) and others. 
   you can find on web. you have a cd drive? or usb 2.0 drive can work,read about it.
   you can also save any partitions, clone drive on spare drive.
3. "format drive", Here it wipes off your old files. 
   and you can create partitions if you want.
4. install operating system, with CD.
5. remove CD, enjoy.